# Joining 3 tables -SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables:

entry:

```
                   _________________________
                  |memberid | tourid | year |
                  --------------------------
                  |  118    |  24    | 2011 |
                  |  224    |  40    | 2012 |
                  ___________________________
```

member:

```
   ______________________________________________________________________________________________
  | memid | lname | fname   | memtype | phone | handicap | joindate | memteam | gender | lifemem |
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 118   | James | Melissa | Junior  | 50154 |   30     | 2004-5-5 |  TeamB  |  F     |   0     |  
  | 138   | Allset| Micheal | Senior  | 45215 |   30     | 2008-4-2 |  TeamC  |  M     |   1     |
   _______________________________________________________________________________________________
```

tournament:

```
   _______________________________________
  |tiourid | tourname | tourtype | active | 
  ----------------------------------------  
  | 24     |  London  | social   |   y    |
  | 40     |  Leeds   | open     |   n    |
   _______________________________________
```

I am trying to achieve->  Member id and last name for every member who has ever entered tournament 40

This is my code:

```
        SELECT entry.memberid, member.lastname, entry.year from entry join member on entry.MemberId 
         = member.MemberId  where tourid = 40;
```

I am not sure the above code is right, would some one please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems correct. Just use `DISTINCT` to prevent duplicate member details in case any member participated in tournament id 40 multiple times in the same year.

```
SELECT distinct entry.memberid,
       member.lastname, 
       entry.year 
  from entry join member on entry.MemberId = member.MemberId  
 where entry.tourid = 40;
```

Comment: Can I use the same code for this question as well? ->Member id, last name and year for every entry in tournament 40. Thank you

Comment: Yes. You can use same code as year is part of this query.